# PonyORM SQLite Entity

Tags: sqlite, orm

```html
import telebot
import config
from pony.orm import *
from databases import Database

# bot = telebot.TeleBot(TOKEN)
bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.TOKEN)

db = Database("sqlite:///shows.db")

class Person(db.Entity):
    pass



db.bind(provider="sqlite", filename="database.sqlite", create_db=True)







# RUN
bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
```

**Ошибка**

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "bot.py", line 11, in 
class Person(db.Entity):
AttributeError: 'Database' object has no attribute 'Entity'

**В чем проблема почему говорит что нету такого атрибута? помогите**

Comment: Потому что вы использовали какой-то непонятный `databases.Database` который не имеет никакого отношения к PonyORM

Comment: А повторял как в документации. а что тогда надо использовать что бы работало с PyORM?

Comment: Нет, ваш код не соответствует документации, потому что в документации PonyORM нет такой строчки `from databases import Database`

Comment: Да но там просто создается переменная db = Database() Но у меня не получалось так просто написать, можете помочь?

Comment: В документации используется родной класс `pony.orm.Database`, а вы воткнули какой-то непонятный сторонний класс `databases.Database`, поэтому и не работает. Чтобы работало — просто скопируйте код из документации и не лепите никакой отсебятины с модулем `databases`

Comment: Ой действительно, Спасибо вам)